# Vanila Javascript: Smooth Scroll Not Working

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am currently making a website. I am making a vanila javascript smooth scroll. I have triple-checked but everything seems right. Please help me out. Highly Appreciated.

The error states:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

My code:

```
function smoothScroll(target, duration){
    var target = document.querySelector(target);
    var targetPosition = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var startPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    var distance = targetPosition -startPosition;
    var startTime = null;

    function animation(currentTime){
        if(startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
        var timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
        var run = ease(timeElapsed,startPosition,distance,duration);
        window.scrollTo(0, run);
        if(timeElapsed < duration) requestAnimationFrame(animation)
    }
    function ease(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d/2;
        if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
        t--;
        return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    };

    
    requestAnimationFrame(animation);

}



var section1 = document.querySelector('section1');
section1.addEventListener('click',function(){
    smoothScroll('.section2', 1000)
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box1"><a href="" class="section1">I cool</a></div>
    <div class="box2"><a class="section2" href="#">I cool</a></div>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.box1 {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 3rem;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: crimson;
}

.box2 {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 3rem;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: rgb(223, 255, 41);
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('section1')` would select an element with the _tag name_ `section1` - of which there are none. Your element has a _class_ of that name, so the selector needs to be `.section1`

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with the built in scroll method

Javascript:

```
element.scrollIntoView();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

CSS:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```